# Function spaces- why are functions a vector space rather than an algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have Calculus + Analytic geometry credits and what I'm reading as an introduction to Functional analysis is to define $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ and call the functions a vector space and that; when do I also define $(f \times g)(x) = f(x) \times g(x)$? It's confusing me about what is a linear function and what's not a linear function.

Comment: It depends on the nature of the codomain. Often times the codomain is a vector space and so the functions inherit a vector space structure. If the codomain also happens to be a field, the functions will inherit an algebra structure. The space of functions borrows much of its structure from the codomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer.. The structure of the space of functions from $X$ to $Y$ depends heavily on the nature of the codomain $Y$. If $Y$ is a vector space, the space of functions will naturally inherit the vector space structure in the usual way. If $Y$ also happens to be a field, then the space of functions will even further be an algebra since you will be able to multiply elements in the codomain and track that back to the functions themselves naturally. It will however not in general be a field since you can define functions that are supported on opposite pieces to give a product of $0$. In order for the algebra of functions to be a field, you will need to add more structure by focusing on certain classes of functions.

Comment: To add a bit, it depens on what you want to explore. The usual choice of functional analysis (at least at the introduction) is to find out properties of vector spaces and maps between them. But this is in a way arbitrary choice given by the interest of mathematicians. So treating function spaces as vector spaces says that you are interested in the vector space properties (at the moment). You will use algebra definition when interested in algebra properties.